# Developing a complex dictionary structure in C#. Have the dictionary structure in python but now I'm trying to write it in C#

Tags: python, c#, .net, dictionary, data-structures

I'm trying to replicate a python dictionary in C# and then access it members to set values of variables.

Below is the python dictionary that I need to write in C# syntax:

```
VPC_DEFAULTS = {
    # prod
    "aws://1234/us-east-1": {
        "vpc_name": "vpc-us-east-1-it-prod",
        "subnets": {
            "application": [ "subnet-1234", "subnet-9764" ],
            "data":        [ "subnet-4323", "subnet-3456" ],
            "edge":        [ "subnet-1763", "subnet-1373" ],
        }
    },
    # dev
    "aws://34652/us-east-1": {
        "vpc_name": "vpc-us-east-1-it-dev",
        "subnets": {
            "application": [ 
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-7623", "az": "us-east-1a" },
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-7424", "az": "us-east-1b" },
            ],
            "data":        [ 
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-4673", "az": "us-east-1b" },
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-1853", "az": "us-east-1a" },
            ],
            "edge":        [ 
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-8414", "az": "us-east-1a" },
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-7423", "az": "us-east-1b" },
            ],
        }
    },
}
```

And then once we have this dictionary set up I need to set the values of the following variabes:

```
vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup( self, "VPC", 
            vpc_name=VPC_DEFAULTS[ self.environment ][ "vpc_name" ]
        )

iSubnets = {}
        for layer in VPC_DEFAULTS[ self.environment ][ "subnets" ]:
            member = iSubnets[ layer ] = []
            for subnet_info in VPC_DEFAULTS[ self.environment ][ "subnets" ][ layer ]:
                member.append(
                    ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_attributes( self, "SubnetFromId-" + layer + "-" + subnet_info["subnet_id"], 
                        subnet_id=subnet_info["subnet_id"], 
                        availability_zone=subnet_info["az"] 
                    ) 
                )
```

In the above the variable names are being set from the dictionary using python. I'm need to set the variables names vpc_name and the array iSubnets in the similar way in c#.

Any help with the following would be great as I'm pretty new to c#.

Comment: @CaiusJard How do you do a "Paste json as classes"?

Comment: Ugh. In C# we'd do this as a proper class, with named properties and data containers of various sensible types, not a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>[]>>[]>>>[]>` or whatever. You could get a reasonable what there by copying the JSONny looking bit, fixing it up so it was valid JSON and doing a "Paste json as classes". You could, I suppose, JSON parse it to a dynamic too, if you love that "let's figure it out at runtime" flying by the seat of your pants stuff :)

Comment: Note; Googling "paste json as classes" may have taken less time and probably delivered a better result (examples, screenshots) than asking me here, waiting 30 mins for me to notice the comment and say "copy your fixed up json then look in the edit menu". I've actually just finished writing up an answer that is virtually the same process as I'm recommending to you- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388363/c-a-strings-split-method-getting-certain-information-from-string/63388576#63388576 - take your Python, remove the #comments (or rename as keys), paste into QTIO, play with the result

Comment: @CaiusJard I wrote the comment and had immediately got the solution.
Anyways for future reference I'm posting the link https://www.michael-whelan.net/paste-json-as-classes/#:~:text=This%20feature%20allows%20you%20to,%E2%80%9CPaste%20JSON%20As%20Classes.%E2%80%9D

Answer (score 0):

Better to Create a class structure like below and de-serialize your JSON to an object of the Class and then do the operation

```
 public class VPCS    {
        public List<DataCenter> dataCenter { get; set; } 
    }
     public class DataCenter    {
        public string vpc_name { get; set; } 
        public Subnets subnets { get; set; } 
    }
     public class Subnets    {
        public List<Application> application { get; set; } 
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; } 
        public List<Edge> edge { get; set; } 
    }
    public class Application    {
        public string subnet_id { get; set; } 
        public string az { get; set; } 
    }
    public class Datum    {
        public string subnet_id { get; set; } 
        public string az { get; set; } 
    }
    public class Edge    {
        public string subnet_id { get; set; } 
        public string az { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: This looks like the right direction but could you provide some more help on how I can potentially deserialize this and use it to assign the two variables? @AnsilF

Comment: In C# word Newtonsoft is the way to go on deserializing .Please refer https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm