# C#, a String's Split() method getting certain information from string

Tags: c#

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "user": {
                "id": "12345678",
                "displayName": "name",
                "subscriptionProducts": [
                    {
                        "id": "123456",
                        "emoteSetID": "123456",
                        "name": "name",
                        "__typename": "SubscriptionProduct"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "123456",
                        "emoteSetID": "123456",
                        "name": "name2000",
                        "__typename": "SubscriptionProduct"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "123456",
                        "emoteSetID": "123456",
                        "name": "name_3000",
                        "__typename": "SubscriptionProduct"
                    }
                ],
                "self": null,
                "__typename": "User"
            },
            "currentUser": null,
            "requestInfo": {
                "countryCode": "US",
                "__typename": "RequestInfo"
            }
        },
        "extensions": {
            "durationMilliseconds": 31,
            "operationName": "ChannelPage_SubscribeButton_User",
            "requestID": "1234124124asd123412425151245124"
        }
    }
]
```

I get this response in my C# application and I am trying to just grab the "ID" which is 12345678
after {"data":{"user":{"**id**":"**12345678**"... blah blah blah

I wrote a code but it does not work

`string value = httpreqResp.Split(new[] { "/"id/": /"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('"')[0];`
Can someone help if possible

Comment: This is JSON, why not just parse it as JSON?

Comment: I already parsed it , I just need to split it and just to get the 12345678 part from whole string

Comment: how did you parse it? you just have the data as `String`. Load it into a POCO or use sth like Json.Net's Linq API (`JObject`)

Comment: "I already parsed it" - no, you didn't, if you are asking about splitting the string. Had you parsed it you'd already have the result you need.

Comment: Use the property path to get the value of the attribute you want, you don't even nded to deserialize it first.

Comment: I parsed it through api -_-
var response = httpRequest.Get($"https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login={channel}");
 var data = response.ToString();

you need to add headers and other stuff in order to get all of that info. 
that is why I did not post it. Just posted the json response.

Comment: @Godlike - That's not parsing. You're just getting the raw response.

Comment: True , I got raw response .

Comment: @Godlike - Have you tried Caius' excellent answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You go to http://QuickType.io and paste your json in
- You set some other options like the name of the root class
- It generates you a bunch of C# - I would have done this with your json but I'm on a cellphone and QTIO doesn't work on a cell; can't paste the json in, so I had to use the example temperatures.json
- The generated C# looks like this, a host of classes that represent the objects in the JSON then some handy one shot methods for converting from/to the JSON:

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using QuickType;
//
//    var temperatures = Temperatures.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Temperatures
    {
        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public Description Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Dictionary<string, Datum> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Datum
    {
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("anomaly")]
        public string Anomaly { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Description
    {
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("units")]
        public string Units { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("base_period")]
        public string BasePeriod { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Temperatures
    {
        public static Temperatures FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Temperatures>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Temperatures self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

- you get your response string str from the server
- you write a line of code like `var parsed = YourRootClassName.FromJson(str)`
- and then your desired data is available in e.g `parsed[0].Data.User.Id`

You can do a similar thing with a visual studio's "Paste Json as classes" function, except it doesn't write the handy deserializer bits for you like QuickType does. Those parts don't change though, so if QTIO ever went away, this answer could still stand by blending the deser methods above with the resulting c# from doing a paste as classes

If you really want to do it using string split, just split on `"` and it'll be the seventh element of the resulting array. Maybe. It'll be fragile as hell, which is why you should parse it

Edit: json2charp can be used from a cell, their version looks like this:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class SubscriptionProduct    {
        public string id { get; set; } 
        public string emoteSetID { get; set; } 
        public string name { get; set; } 
        public string __typename { get; set; } 
    }

    public class User    {
        public string id { get; set; } 
        public string displayName { get; set; } 
        public List<SubscriptionProduct> subscriptionProducts { get; set; } 
        public object self { get; set; } 
        public string __typename { get; set; } 
    }

    public class RequestInfo    {
        public string countryCode { get; set; } 
        public string __typename { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Data    {
        public User user { get; set; } 
        public object currentUser { get; set; } 
        public RequestInfo requestInfo { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Extensions    {
        public int durationMilliseconds { get; set; } 
        public string operationName { get; set; } 
        public string requestID { get; set; } 
    }

    public class MyArray    {
        public Data data { get; set; } 
        public Extensions extensions { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public List<MyArray> MyArray { get; set; } 
    }
```

And would be used like:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responseStringFromWebservice); 
var id = myDeserializedClass.MyArray[0].Data.User.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a JSON string,

You can JsonSerializer.Deserialize to convert it to a C# class.

First create your own classes to store data,like this

```
    public class SubscriptionProduct    {
        public string id { get; set; } 
        public string emoteSetID { get; set; } 
        public string name { get; set; } 
        public string __typename { get; set; } 
    }

    public class User    {
        public string id { get; set; } 
        public string displayName { get; set; } 
        public List<SubscriptionProduct> subscriptionProducts { get; set; } 
        public object self { get; set; } 
        public string __typename { get; set; } 
    }

    public class RequestInfo    {
        public string countryCode { get; set; } 
        public string __typename { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Data    {
        public User user { get; set; } 
        public object currentUser { get; set; } 
        public RequestInfo requestInfo { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Extensions    {
        public int durationMilliseconds { get; set; } 
        public string operationName { get; set; } 
        public string requestID { get; set; } 
    }

    public class MyArray    {
        public Data data { get; set; } 
        public Extensions extensions { get; set; } 
    }

    public class MyClass {
        public List<MyArray> MyArray { get; set; } 
    }
```

Then use this:

```
var mydata = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Please show using the OP's JSON text how to parse get the value that the OP is asking for.

Comment: I would like explanation either regex or split string . Json string class e.t.c is too hard to understand and it is way too inconvenient to do each time, if you can please help with that would be nice. If not it is okay too . 
Thank you

Comment: Thanks, my code will work correctly, but your down-vote, hints to other visitors that JSON is not correct answer :).

Comment: I did not downvote, but the question was stated that I do not like using Json .